# Simulation results structured for csv-compare

Tags: openmodelica

Is there a function or an open-source library to generate simulation results of a tested Modelica library (test library) in csv format and structured to be directly suitable for csv-compare?
(https://github.com/modelica-tools/csv-compare)

So the function/library shall simulate all simulatable models (examples) of the test library and generate csv results structured according to the class tree (package structure) of test library. The generated results shall be processable by (not part of the function/library)

```
compare.exe --mode csvTreeCompare ...
```

P.S. I have not sufficient reputation to add a tag like "csv-compare". :-(

Comment: Do you mean something like the tool that generates the library coverage tests for OpenModelica? See https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/master/Modelica_4.0.0/Modelica_4.0.0.html

Comment: Yes, I think so. But the results must be structures to be consequently processable by csv-compare.

Answer (score 1):

There is [OpenModelicaLibraryTesting](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelicaLibraryTesting) which generates library coverage results for [OpenModelica](https://openmodelica.org/).

It can take Modelica libraries and will compile, simulate and compare against reference files and generates HTML pages.
So for the Modelica Standard Library the tool uses reference results from https://github.com/modelica/MAP-LIB_ReferenceResults in mat format, but it can also handle CSV results.

If I remember correctly the compare results API function from OpenModelica used in the scripts of OpenModelicaLibraryTesting uses `csv-compare` in some form.

---

Maybe this is a bit more than you need. You can also write your own MOS / Python / Julia script and use [diffSimulationResults](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#diffsimulationresults).

Comment: This seems to be nearly what I'm looking for. https://github.com/modelica/MAP-LIB_ReferenceResults is indeed the right example, wanting to **generate** reference results of my Modelica library in that way - regarding directory structure and csv-format. Any option OpenModelicaLibraryTesting can do this?

Comment: OpenModelicaLibraryTesting can handle result directories that are "flat" list of files like `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller.csv` and structured like the MSL references `Modelica/Blocks/Examples/PID_Controller.csv`.

Comment: That's good. Does "can handle" also mean to generate simulation results like `Modelica/Blocks/Examples/PID_Controller/PID_Controller.csv`, etc.?

Comment: They should be generated during the simulation and than compared to the reference file. Not sure if they get deleted or not. But I guess at this point you need to check the script itself: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelicaLibraryTesting/blob/master/testmodel.py#L472

Comment: Many thanks! I will look deeper there.